# Cantor Set is closed, uncountable and has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set

In Royden and Fitzpatrick's Real Analysis, there's this part of proving that the Cantor Set is closed, uncountable and has measure zero that I don't get.

[image]

Here is how I interpret the first part:

$C_1 = [0,\frac{1}{3}] \bigcup [\frac{2}{3},1]$

$c_1$ is in $[0,\frac{1}{3}]$ xor $[\frac{2}{3},1]$.

Let $F_1$ be the interval which does not contain $c_1$.

That is, $F_1 = \begin{cases}
[0,\frac{1}{3}] & \text{ if } \ c_1 \notin [0,\frac{1}{3}] \\ 
[\frac{2}{3},1] & \text{ if } \ c_1 \notin [\frac{2}{3},1] 
\end{cases}$

For the part where it says, "One of the two disjoint Cantor intervals in C2 whose union is F1 fails to contain the point c2", are there any intervals in C2 whose union is F1? There is no mention of this in the errata of the book so it's likely right.

From what I know, $C_2 = [0,\frac{1}{9}] \bigcup [\frac{2}{9},\frac{3}{9}] \bigcup [\frac{6}{9},\frac{7}{9}] \bigcup [\frac{8}{9},\frac{9}{9}]$, so it seems none of those intervals combine to $F_1$.

Could R&F have meant to say "One of the two disjoint Cantor intervals in C2 whose union is *in* F1"?

That is,

$F_2 = \begin{cases}
[0,\frac{1}{9}] \bigcup [\frac{2}{9},\frac{3}{9}] & \text{ if } c_2 \notin [0,\frac{1}{9}] \bigcup [\frac{2}{9},\frac{3}{9}]\\ 
[\frac{6}{9},\frac{7}{9}] \bigcup [\frac{8}{9},\frac{9}{9}] & \text{ if } c_2 \notin [\frac{6}{9},\frac{7}{9}] \bigcup [\frac{8}{9},\frac{9}{9}]
\end{cases}$

Comment: Replace "whose union is $F_k$" by "which are contained in $F_k$", or by "whose union is $F_k\cap C_{k+1}$". In other words: You're right.

Comment: @DanielFischer is $F_2$ in $F_1$ (see comment of Topology below) ?

Comment: Yes, one must always take $F_{k+1} \subset F_k$, since one uses that the intersection of a sequence of nested compact sets is nonempty in the proof of uncountability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could R&F have meant to say "One of the two disjoint Cantor intervals in C2 whose union is in F1"?

Yes. Thanks @DanielFischer [Cantor Set is closed, uncountable and has measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819281/cantor-set-is-closed-uncountable-and-has-measure-zero?noredirect=1#comment1693219_819281)

Comment: Is $F_2$ contained in $F_1$?

Comment: @Topology forgot this already but I think so

Comment: I think it might not be!

Comment: @Topology why?...

Comment: @Topology 'intersection of a sequence of nested compact sets is nonempty' or something. see comment above